# raid problems after power outage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mdadm, raid5

I was in the middle of copying data to a raid5 from a raid 1 when the power went out. Initially, I figured the raid was lost, so I zeroed the super-blocks. fdisked all the drives in the raid 5 and deleted the partitions, and saved the partition table afterwords. Now, as i'm re-creating the array about half an hour into the build I get this error:

```
    [Dec19 11:48] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  +0.003870] kernel BUG at /build/linux-W6HB68/linux-4.4.0/drivers/ata/sata_mv.c:2120!
[  +0.000000] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP
[  +0.000000] Modules linked in: serio_raw input_leds lpc_ich e752x_edac shpchp edac_core 8250_fintek mac_hid ib_iser rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_sa ib_mad ib_core ib_addr i                                                                     scsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi autofs4 btrfs raid10 raid0 multipath linear raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor r                                                                     aid1 raid6_pq libcrc32c hid_generic psmouse usbhid e1000 pata_acpi hid sky2 sata_mv fjes
[  +0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 178 Comm: scsi_eh_5 Not tainted 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu
[  +0.000000] Hardware name: Intel                                  /SE7520BD23D, BIOS SE7520BD23.86B.P.03.00.0019.102020051047 10/20/2005
[  +0.000000] task: ffff8801199a72c0 ti: ffff880035348000 task.ti: ffff880035348000
[  +0.000000] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc003fbb3>]  [<ffffffffc003fbb3>] mv_qc_prep+0x213/0x230 [sata_mv]
[  +0.000000] RSP: 0018:ffff88003534ba30  EFLAGS: 00010006
[  +0.000000] RAX: ffff880035b374e0 RBX: ffff88003599dd70 RCX: 0000000000000047
[  +0.000000] RDX: ffff880035b374ea RSI: ffff8800db8ef060 RDI: ffff88003599dd70
[  +0.000000] RBP: ffff88003534ba48 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000001
[  +0.000000] R10: ffff88003534bb70 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 000000000000003f
[  +0.000000] R13: ffff880035b8f418 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: ffff88003599dd70
[  +0.000000] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88011fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  +0.000000] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[  +0.000000] CR2: 00007f913ec00b24 CR3: 0000000001e0a000 CR4: 00000000000006f0
[  +0.000000] Stack:
[  +0.000000]  ffff88003599c000 0000000000000001 ffff88003599de80 ffff88003534baa0
[  +0.000000]  ffffffff815dab0a ffff8800db8ef098 ffffffff81e2c360 ffff88003534bb70
[  +0.000000]  0000000281d18758 ffff88003534bbe0 ffff88003599de80 0000000000000000
[  +0.000000] Call Trace:
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff815dab0a>] ata_qc_issue+0x15a/0x390
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff815db042>] ata_exec_internal_sg+0x302/0x600
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff815db3a9>] ata_exec_internal+0x69/0xc0
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff813c966b>] ? blk_peek_request+0x4b/0x290
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff815e49d6>] ata_read_log_page.part.11+0x196/0x1d0
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff815e5ba1>] ata_eh_analyze_ncq_error+0x111/0x280
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff815e5daa>] ata_eh_link_autopsy+0x9a/0x950
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff815e668b>] ata_eh_autopsy+0x2b/0xf0
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff815efc42>] sata_pmp_error_handler+0x12/0x30
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffffc003f953>] mv_pmp_error_handler+0x93/0xa0 [sata_mv]
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff815e9730>] ata_scsi_port_error_handler+0x430/0x770
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff815e427d>] ? ata_scsi_cmd_error_handler+0x11d/0x150
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff815e9b10>] ata_scsi_error+0xa0/0xe0
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff815bba6b>] scsi_error_handler+0xdb/0x8a0
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff81833e16>] ? __schedule+0x3b6/0xa30
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff815bb990>] ? scsi_eh_get_sense+0x240/0x240
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff810a0ba8>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff810a0ad0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff8183898f>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
[  +0.000000]  [<ffffffff810a0ad0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[  +0.000000] Code: 66 89 48 0a e9 43 ff ff ff c6 47 35 30 e9 24 fe ff ff be 1c 08 00 00 48 c7 c7 68 32 04 c0 e8 55 18 04 c1 8b 53 58 e9 93 fe ff ff <0f> 0b 48 83 e2 df                                                                      48 89 57 20 e9 4f fe ff ff 0f 1f 40 00 66 2e
[  +0.000000] RIP  [<ffffffffc003fbb3>] mv_qc_prep+0x213/0x230 [sata_mv]
[  +0.000000]  RSP <ffff88003534ba30>
[  +0.000000] ---[ end trace 0d078601e6e4aaef ]---
```

I'v tried rebooting, re-seating the cards/ram/disks. As for stack-traces go, this is a new one on me.

Comment: ewww. it looks like someones nightmare

Comment: here's the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1652185

Comment: So this is just a bug with the kernal and not a problem with one of the drives or the raid card?

Comment: it's hard to tell from just that snippet, but the fact that the stack trace knows there is a bug reported means that 1) There is a known bug 2) The patch has not been back ported to your kernel  - patch or upgrade the kernel

Comment: kernel BUG at /build/linux-W6HB68/linux-4.4.0/drivers/ata/sata_mv.c:2120!

Comment: Well, hopefully my MOBO will take a new kernal.

Comment: it seems that bug has been backported to your kernel, if there is a hardware raid controller then boot into that and create a virtual disk, if it's software RAID then use another app, begin bemoaning to decision makers that you don't have an uninterruptible power supply

Comment: Think it may now have something to do with mdadm trying to recover a bad array. Still keeps trying to recover the array after I deleted the GPT tables. Zeroed the super-blocks and dded 200mb of zeros to the begeining and end of the sectors. Damn that is annoying.